# using MacBook Pro as keyboad

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb

I was wanting to know if i could use my laptop as a keyboard, i am wanting to plug a device into my laptop's USB port and send keystrokes from the keyboard out of the USB port, the connected device would be things such as: raspberry pi, arduino, servers. The program will be similar to a keylogger,  I do have programing knowledge, please give me advice on how to make this project possible, or tell me if a solution has already been found. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what is being asked here.  Are you trying to connect to a device that has an old-fashioned 9-pin or 25-pin serial port on it, like many servers and routers still do?  If that's the case, you need a terminal emulation program like [ZTerm](http://www.dalverson.com/zterm/) and a [USB-to-serial converter](http://www.amazon.com/TRENDnet-RS-232-Serial-Converter-TU-S9/dp/B0007T27H8).

Comment: I am Trying to send the keystrokes from my laptop out of the usb port, so that my laptop will act like a normal external keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Type2Phone](http://houdah.com/type2Phone/), but it only works with Bluetooth and not USB.

The website says that it supports iPhone, iPad, and AppleTV, but it might also work with other devices according to the comments in [this blog post](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/15/use-mac-as-bluetooth-keyboard-for-iphone-ipad-android-type2phone/).

Comment: I was Thinking of making a simple command line tool using xcode, i am reading the USB documentation to find out how to write this program. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I am wanting to make something similar to a keylogger. but the keylogger will output to the usb port.